# Binary Search Tree (C), segmentation fault in Insertion function

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Im trying to create an insertion function on an binary search tree.
I looked at other questions here but they re not like my problem.

I can compile it but it crashes on the commented line below:

```
void insertNode(TreeNode** r, int n) {

TreeNode* novono;

    novono = createNode(n);
    if (*r == NULL){ //corrected
        *r = novono;
        (*r) -> right = NULL;
        (*r) -> left = NULL;
        (*r) -> data = n;
    }
    if (n < ((*r) -> data))
        insertNode(&((*r) -> left), n); //SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE
    if (n > ((*r) -> data))
        insertNode(&((*r) -> right), n); //SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE

}
```

This is the main function that tries to insert ints from a vector:

```
int main() {

#define MAX 15

TreeNode*   root    = NULL;
bool        OK      = true;
int         i       = 0, 
            n,
            V[MAX] = { 50, 10, 70, 2, 1, 13, 15, 65, 69, 77, 11, 3, 80, 76,   64}; 

    initTree(&root);
printf("Passou da inicialização");
    for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++ ) {
        printf("[%d] ", V[i]);

        insertNode(&root, V[i]);
        }
```

And this is the inicialization function that is executed before the insertion. (i dont think it is the problem, but im putting it here just cause i know you will ask for it).

```
void clearTree( TreeNode** r) {

    if ( *r != NULL) {
        printf("Clear %d\n", (*r)->data);
        clearTree(&(*r)->left);
        clearTree(&(*r)->right);
        free(*r);
        *r = NULL;
        }
}

void initTree( TreeNode** r) {

    if (*r != NULL)
        clearTree( &(*r) );

    if( *r == NULL)
        printf("Limpeza com sucesso !!\n"); 
    else    
        printf("Limpeza sem sucesso !!\n"); 
}
```

Create Node function as requested:

```
TreeNode* createNode(int n) {

    TreeNode* newNode = (TreeNode*) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));

    if ( newNode != NULL) {
        newNode->data   = n;
        newNode->left   = 
        newNode->right  = NULL;
        }

    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: `if (*r = NULL)` ---> `if (*r == NULL)`

Comment: You should try to provide a minimal test case that reproduces your problem. Also, it is likely that while making it you'll find your answer.

Comment: Can you also post the code for `createNode`? With the one I wrote, the program does not crash.

Comment: done. Im starting to think there is a problem with my compiler or something, segmentation fault in insert node recursive call, doesnt matter what i do...

Comment: Try running your code on http://codepad.org or http://ideone.com

Comment: You're also creating a new node in every call to `insertNode`, even if you don't really insert it. And if `createNode` ever returns `NULL`, you'll try to dereference it in your next recursive call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On second look, I don't see the crash, but I see a memory leak. Think what happen within the same function with novono if (*r == NULL) was false. I would recommend you to forget this code and try to write it again from scratch and try to avoid of pointers to pointers - **something.

instead of:

```
void insertNode(TreeNode** r, int n)
```

I woud try:

```
/* this error handling would be sufficient for the beginner */
void * xmalloc(size_t size) {
   void * ret = malloc(size);
   if (!ret) { 
      printf("error\n");
      exit(1); 
   }
   return ret;
} 

/* returns root of the tree */
TreeNode * insertNode(TreeNode* r, int n) {
   if (!r) return createNode(n);
   ...
   return r;
}

TreeNode * createNode(int n) {
   TreeNode * ret = xmalloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
   ret->left = left->right = 0;
   ret->data = n;
   return ret;        
}
```

Instead of initTree, just:

```
....
TreeNode * root = 0;
root = insertNode(root, 10);
root = insertNode(root, 12);
root = insertNode(root, 20);
root = insertNode(root, 14);
```

Comment: I wrote it again and it worked. Cant see where the problem was tough, thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3):

Very first look... "if (*r = NULL)" should be "if (*r == NULL)"

Comment: Yeah this was wrong, but the segmentation fault continues in the same place. I think something is wrong here: insertNode(&((*r) -> left), n);

Comment: @Diedre You think? Haven't you checked with a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (n < ((*r) -> data));
    insertNode(&((*r) -> left), n);
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (n < ((*r) -> data)) {
    ;
}
insertNode(&((*r) -> left), n);
```

So very likely NOT what you want.

(GCC with `-Wempty-body` (included in `-Wextra`) would have warned you about it.)

Comment: oh my, a lot of ridiculous things i didnt see cause i did it in a rush, but im sure the error is in the insertnode recursive call... (i corrected the; and tested....). this was there cause i commented the insert line for debuguing.